# What do the Posttype values in the schema of Stack Exchange data dump mean?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki, data-dump

I was exploring stack exchange database and came to know there can be various types of posts. Among them, there were many post types that I did not understand. The names of those post types are

1. Orphaned tag wiki
2. Tag wiki excerpt
3. Tag wiki
4. Moderator nomination
5. "Wiki placeholder" (seems to only be the election description)
6. Privilege wiki

Can someone please elaborate on these?

Comment: Related: [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/168244)

Comment: @Werner I have looked at it but they haven't described these post types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

3. Orphaned tag wiki

This are the wiki texts for tags that are removed by the clean-up script. When the tag is removed (because no questions have the tag anymore) you can no longer reach the wiki.

4. Tag wiki excerpt

This is the tag excerpt for a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info), you see the text in the box at the top of the page. To know which post belongs to which tag you'll find the foreignkeys in the tag table, for example:

```
select t.tagname
     , e.body as excerpt
     , w.body as wiki
from tags t
inner join posts e on e.id = t.excerptpostid
inner join posts w on w.id = t.wikipostid
where t.tagname = 'javascript'
```

5. Tag wiki

This posts row holds the wiki text for a tag. You can use the above query to find the wiki post that belongs to a tag.

6. Moderator nomination

When an election is run, candidates provide a small nomination text. For each candidate you'll find a post. On a site you'll find previous elections under the `/election/[number]` endpoint, for example https://stackoverflow.com/election/5. By limiting the query on the creationdates of the post you'll find the nomination texts for the candidates of that specific election.

```
-- election/5
select score
     , body
     , owneruserid as [User Link]
from posts
where posttypeid = 6 -- nominations
and creationdate between '2014-02-10' 
                 and '2014-02-25'
```

7. "Wiki placeholder"

The posts with this type contain at least the text found at the [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election/8). Their is only one post (so if you go to the first election, you'll find the same text).

Another post is used on the [Tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) as the pay-off, and for the *do ask* and *don't ask* texts of the tour.

```
-- election and tour
select id, score, body
from postswithdeleted
where posttypeid = 7 -- placeholder
```

[image: do and don't ask on tour page]

8. Privilege wiki

Posts of this type hold the text for the privileges found for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). Strangely enough for Stack Overflow only 2 privileges seem to have records. I guess all sites use the network wide defaults for the privileges and only add a post of type 8 if they have slightly different guidance for a privilege. On Super User only [one privilege post](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/580988?opt.textResults=true) exist.

I have all above queries captured [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/580985) in case you want to investigate further. Keep in mind there are differences between what is in [SEDE] and what is in the DataDump, where the former is more complete.