# SEDE logs me out more often than it used to do

Tags: bug, login, data-explorer, session

I'm pretty sure that since a month or so, [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) seems much more eager to get rid of my session and log me out in that process.

I don't mind logging in a couple of times per day, if that helps to reduce resource consumption, but the user experience isn't all that great when it happens.

Here is why: I'm most often in the middle of writing a query for an MSE question, for example [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287130/158100). So I have the edit window open and am creating a new revision of my query. When I click "run," I do notice the button gets grayed-out, as it normally does, but I never get any result back. There is also no error message.

To recover from this I have to copy the SQL text I have typed, open a new tab and load SEDE, log in, switch back to the stalled tab, refresh, paste the SQL text, run query. Repeat the process after 10 minutes.

If the intended behavior is to log users out of their session on such short notice (I recall sessions lived for 24 hours), can there then be a slightly better handling in the browser of that state, so it is clear you're logged out once you click the run button?

I prefer, however, to have the longer allowed sessions back.

I'm experiencing this behavior mostly in Chrome on Win 10.

Comment: True, I lost the session couple of times while writing a query, even though it was matter of minutes. Ended up writing this as anonymous user.

Comment: I just never log in anymore; haven't for years. Captchas are less annoying.

Comment: Ah, reminds me of [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182256/extend-or-remove-dataexplorer-timeout).

Comment: @bluefeet don't you now have access to the server log to see if it is indeed an app domain recycle? But it does look similar indeed.

Comment: Not a dev over here @rene.

Comment: Just pretend you're one ..  I have faith in you ...

Answer (score 3):

Can't agree more. This is extremely inconvenient and causes UI malfunction:

- If I leave a query window open, after some time it becomes inoperative - impossible to execute and the editor glitches
- I have to login every time I visit the site - which I don't have to at other SE sites and the majority of other sites on the Net. Everyone except security-critical sites like banks at least provide an option to "remember me" when logging in.

Comment: Considering that the SE doesn't seem wanting to fix this problem, I would use some browser add-on to work around this session expiration problem from the client side. Btw, the data SE is an opensource tool, available [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer) - in theory, anybody could produce pull requests for them.