# 500 Error when attempting to post an update to my profile page on dataSE

Tags: support, profile-page, data-explorer, posting, 500-server-error

Looks like an intermittent issue. I couldn't update my profile page on dataSE a few hours ago:

[image: 500 error on edit profile page of dataSE]

but now its working. Any explanation?

Answer (score 2):

It very rarely happens, but sometimes this can trigger at the *precise* point where a new build has just finished being deployed. And I mean the window in which it's possible is *extremely* (fractions of a second) small. I can recall fewer than 10 times where this has happened.

I'm 99.98% certain that's what happened. But if it wasn't, then it was something else that's extremely unlikely to ever happen again (most likely due to a build).

**Edit**

Looks like this wasn't due to a build, but it's definitely due to something similar to that - a very random thing that's unlikely to happen again (and extremely difficult to go back and figure out).

It's definitely *not* the person I secretly pay to occasionally visit our data center and unplug a random cable just because it's so much fun to watch Nick Craver when that happens. Definitely not that.

Comment: Nope. "rev 2016.11.15.53" - last build was made 13 days before this bug happened, so can't really be the case.

Comment: Well, there's that .. and the chaos monkey might also be on the payroll.

Comment: Same monkey who lost his keys. I see. ;)

Comment: @TimPost but I do suspect there might a slightly bigger issue as [my bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287142/sede-logs-me-out-more-often-than-it-used-to-do) is also related to app domain recycles (who are also build/deploy related). When you find the keys to the DC maybe hand them to bluefeet to investigate if Nick didn't  get crushed under one of his shinny servers ...